# What does it mean for a property to "exist" in NAnt?

Tags: nant

Can anyone explain what it means for a property to "exist" in Nant? I have some weird behaviour with the following build script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="Test.Project" default="doIt">
  <!-- property name="test.prop" value="OK" / -->

  <target name="doIt">
    <if test="${property::exists ('test.prop')}">
        <echo>Before ${test.prop}</echo>
    </if>

    <foreach item="String" in="1,2,3" delim="," property="test.prop">
        <echo>${test.prop}</echo>
    </foreach>

    <if test="${property::exists ('test.prop')}">
        <echo>After ${test.prop}</echo>
    </if>
  </target>
</project>
```

Defining `test.prop` results in the "Before OK", "1", "2", "3", "After OK" sequence of echoes that one would expect, however if test.prop is not defined at the start (as in the code above), I get the "1", "2", "3", then the following error:

```
Property evaluation failed.
Expression: After ${test.prop}
                    ^^^^^^^^^
    Property 'test.prop' has not been set.
```

i.e. the property passes the `property::exists` test, but then behaves as if it should have failed.

Is this a bug in NAnt, or should I actually be using some test other than `property::exists` to determine whether I can access a property after it's been used in a `<foreach>`?

[I found this in NAnt 0.90, but updating to NAnt 0.92 has the same behaviour]

Comment: FWIW, confirmed the same behaviour on 0.85 also.

Comment: I'd say it's arguably a bug, possibly in `foreach`.  [It specifies](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/foreach.html) "The property value is stored before the loop is done, and restored when the loop is finished. The property is returned to its normal value once it is used" - so it reverts to having no value, but not to not existing, which sort of makes sense - it's now defined (the `foreach` task did that), but has no value, as that's what it was "set to" before the task was run

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming a bug in <foreach>, although I'd also argue that properties::exists is failing to meet its implied contract, i.e. if you pass the properties::exists test then you shouldn't get a "has not been set" error!

Comment: Yep, `property::exists` should probably do some sort of "nullability" check, if it's possible for tasks (potentially 3rd party tasks in other assemblies) to cause a property to get into this state.

Comment: I hadn't considered 3rd party tasks; just fixing the behaviour of `<foreach>` is not going to be enough :-(

Comment: Seems it has a [bug report](https://github.com/nant/nant/issues/84) already.  Perhaps you could add this example as another case of it occuring?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is in the comments: a bug perhaps in `<foreach>`